# Python `dict` indexed by tuple: Getting a slice of the pie

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, tuples

Let's say I have

```
my_dict = {
  ("airport", "London"): "Heathrow",
  ("airport", "Tokyo"): "Narita",
  ("hipsters", "London"): "Soho"
}
```

What is an efficient (no scanning of all keys), yet elegant way to get all airports out of this dictionary, i.e. expected output `["Heathrow", "Narita"]`. In databases that can index by tuples, it's usually possible to do something like

```
airports = my_dict.get(("airport",*))
```

(but usually only with the 'stars' sitting at the rightmost places in the tuple since the index usually is only stored in one order).

Since I imagine Python to index dictionary with tuple keys in a similar way (using the keys's inherent order), I imagine there might be a method I could use to slice the index this way?

Edit1: Added expected output

Edit2: Removed last phrase. Added '(no scanning of all keys)' to the conditions to make it clearer.

Comment: What is your expect output . Can you post that too. Your question is bit confusing

Comment: use a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: How large is the input?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: You mean something like `my_dict = { "airport" : { "London" : "Heathrow" , "Tokyo" : "Narita"}}` ? Yes, that would always work. I was wondering whether there is a way to do it efficiently with tuple indices too.

Comment: @MichelMüller: Yes. And nope, with tuples you have to check each key.

Comment: @LutzHorn I'd say up to around 100'000 keys if the dictionary is built like above.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Thanks. In that case the correct answer here is IMO "there is no efficient way to do this operation in python with the suggested data structure - switching to dict of dicts is needed if a sequential scan over all keys is too slow". Feel free to create an answer along these lines, I'd accept that.

Comment: Then I'd use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html) to measure any approach. My guess is that performance will be good enough.

Comment: @MichelMüller: note: the way your question is phrased, that's more like a suggestion, not an answer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You're correct. I've rephrased it a bit to make the emphasis on efficiency clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way your data is currently organized doesn't allow efficient lookup - essentially you have to scan *all the keys*.

Dictionaries are hash tables behind the scenes, and the only way to access a value is to get the hash of the key - and for that, you need the *whole key*.

Use a nested hierarchy like this, so you can do a direct O(1) lookup:

```
my_dict = {
  "airport": {
     "London": "Heathrow",
     "Tokyo": "Narita",
  },
  "hipsters": {
     "London": "Soho"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check `"airport"` is present in the every key in the dictionary.

**Demo**:

```
>>> [value for  key, value in my_dict.items() if  "airport" in key]
['Narita', 'Heathrow']
>>>
```

---

Yes, **Nested dictionary** will be better option.

```
>>> my_dict = {
...   "airport": {
...      "London": "Heathrow",
...      "Tokyo": "Narita",
...   },
...   "hipsters": {
...      "London": "Soho"
...   }
... }
>>> 
>>> if "airport" in my_dict:
...      result = my_dict["airport"].values()
... else:
...      result = []
... 
>>> print result
['Heathrow', 'Narita']
>>>
```

Comment: Basically the same comment here - isn't that doing a sequential scan over all keys?

Comment: @MichelMüller: I think not. Create dictionary of dictionary as you mension in the your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like to avoid, if possible, is to go through all dictionary keys and filter them down.

Why? Why do you think Python is doing the equivalent of a DB full table scan? Filtering a dictionary does not mean sequential scanning it.

Python:

```
[value for  key, value in my_dict.items() if key[0] == "airport"]
```

Output:

```
['Narita', 'Heathrow']
```

Comment: Thanks. `Filtering a dictionary does not mean sequential scanning it.` Could you expand on this? I'm curious how python implements this if not by fully scanning. Does it automatically optimize if I only filter for the first part of the key? What if I do `[value for  key, value in my_dict.items() if key[1] == "Tokyo"]`, would *that* lead to a sequential scan?

Comment: @MichelMüller: check like `if  "Tokyo" in key`

Comment: "sequentially scanning it" - well, that's what your code does.